# Removing an element from a text rendered by Javascript

Tags: javascript, markdown

I have a page with scripts that insert and convert a Markdown file:

```
<head>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/zerodevx/zero-md@2/dist/zero-md.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <zero-md id="text"></zero-md> <!-- the area into which each .md is to be inserted and converted -->
    <script>
      document.getElementById("text").src="CONVERTME1.md";
    </script>
  </article>
</body>
```

The conversion itself works, the text gets displayed. Each .md file will be part of a series, and the scripts will enable me to bypass the process of manually converting the texts, so that I can go back to them for editing frequently and easily. I plan to turn the `getElement` into navigation buttons for the sequence of .md files, like the chapters of a book to flip back and forth. Before creating those buttons, there is an element in each output of the conversion that will have to be regularly removed. It's a string from the top (first line) of each original .md file. It starts with "tags:", followed by one or more keywords. It's used by the Markdown editor (WriteMonkey) for internal search operations, and I intend to keep them on each .md file for later editing (and auto-conversion/updating), while they serve no purpose in the final output on the HTML page. This string gets converted by the `zero-md` script as

```
<p>
  ::before
  "tags: KEYWORD"
</p>
```

inside

```
<zero-md id="text">
  #shadow-root (open)
    <div class="markdown-body">
```

So I tried

```
<script>
  document.getElementByTagName("p::before").contains("tags:").remove();
</script>
```

as the last element inside `<article>`, but it didn't work. Then I tried (in the same place) the jQuery

```
<script>
  $("p::before").contains("tags:").remove();
</script>
```

, but it too didn't work. I wasn't sure about `p::before` and `.contains("tags:")`, so I tried just `p` to see if it would affect any paragraphs of the main text, and it didn't do anything, everything inside `zero-md` would remain intact. I checked that elements outside `zero-md` can be removed. So I assume the problem is that the `p` (or any element) that is supposed to have been converted from the .md file and available for reference is somehow inaccessible by `getElementByTagName` at that moment of parsing.

Any solution?

Tangentially: I tried to replace `getElementById("text")` with `getElementByTagName("zero-md")` (so as to do away with `id="text"`), and it didn't work. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no `getElementByTagName` method. Use `querySelector('zero-md')`, or `getElementsByTagName('zero-md')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wish to strip the first `<p>` tag from the rendered contents. The easiest way to do this looks something like:

```html
<article>
  <zero-md id="text">
    <template data-merge="append">
      <style>
      .markdown-body>p:first-child {
        display: hidden;
      }
      </style>
    </template>
  </zero-md>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("text").src="CONVERTME1.md";
  </script>
</article>
```